# Incomprehensible behavior of I18n.locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-6

Rails 6.0.1, Zeitwerk 2.2.2

---

I'm trying to do a switch between languages in a Rails application. I save the language code in cookies. Then, in the root controller, I check for the presence of this code and, if there is a language code, I apply it:

```rb
class Public::BaseController < ApplicationController
  layout 'public/main'

  before_action :prepare_locale

  private

  def prepare_locale
    cookie_locale = cookies[:locale].presence

    return if cookie_locale.blank?
    return unless I18n.available_locales.include?(cookie_locale.to_sym)

    I18n.locale = cookie_locale
  end
end
```

*I specifically avoided the word `locale`. This word is taken by I18n and it is better for them not to name anything anywhere.*

I also have this helper that I use in view:

```rb
module LocaleHelper
  def current_locale?(locale_code)
    I18n.locale == locale_code.to_sym
  end
end
```

In layout, I hung the lang attribute:

```
html lang="#{locale}"
```

Now I will describe the problem step by step:

1. I'm running the application.
2. In the Chrome browser I open the site. I switch the language. Everything is fine. The locale is in the cookies, it is applied in the application.
3. In parallel I open the site in Safari.
4. I don't choose the language. I'm just refreshing the page. Almost every page update is either EN or RU.

I tried to comment out the code that I showed above. After all, this code is the only one that works with `I18n.locale`.

To begin I commented out the code of the helper. I stopped the application and ran it again. Safari is fine (for now). Next, I just refresh the page in Chrome. And then in Safari `I18n.locale` again began to take on different meanings. I don't understand why this is happening.

Next, I comment on the code in the root controller. Essentially, I now have nothing to change `I18n.locale`. A global search for a project confirms this.

Safari is fine again. And reloading the page in Chrome didn't break anything.

That is, the problem is in the root controller.

To be more precise, in this line:

```rb
I18n.locale = cookie_locale
```

**But what exactly is the problem?** And I don't understand why Rails needs a restart to reset (something).

This code does not execute:

```rb
I18n.locale = cookie_locale
```

It is blocked by checks above. That is, this is normal. But why then on a page in Safari I see a constant change of locale code?

Comment: You should really be using `I18n.with_locale` instead of `I18n.locale =` as the later can leak into subsequent requests served by the same thread/process. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#managing-the-locale-across-requests

Comment: Also cookies is probably the least preferable way to handle setting the locale. On real world example of why this sucks is if I take the URL and copy it and send it to a friend and they open the page and get it in another language. Place the locale in the path or a subdomain. You can use cookies to store a users preferred default locale but it should not be the main mechanism for switching locales.

Comment: @max It seems like you're right. I no longer observe problems. Thank you very much.

Comment: @max About your second message - I think you're right too. Thanks for example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @max I made the following code:

```rb
around_action :prepare_locale

private

def prepare_locale(&action)
  cookie_locale = cookies[:locale].presence || I18n.default_locale

  if I18n.available_locales.include?(cookie_locale.to_sym)
    I18n.with_locale(cookie_locale, &action)
  else
    I18n.with_locale(I18n.default_locale, &action)
  end
end
```

This was based on an example from official documentation: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#internationalization-and-localization